# Android Navigation drawer activity issue

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In Android Studio, I'm creating a new project with sample Navigation Drawer Activity (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MthUx.png)

After project is created, I'm starting it in emulator and testing it (here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erl5pobqCE0):

- Firstly, I tap on hamburger menu icon, the menu opens, I close it (correct).
- Then, I'm tapping and (don't release) moving a cursor right, menu opens (correct).
- After that, I'm trying to repeat a previous action but **menu doesn't open** stucking on ~10px left. Somehow this issue appears from time to time. This is reproduced on Nexus 5X device too. I have no idea what is going on. Any thoughts?

Here's the code: https://github.com/akoshman/NavigationDrawerSample

Comment: show the codes how you implemented this

Comment: @StepanMaksymov Here's the code: https://github.com/akoshman/NavigationDrawerSample